# Is it possible to save Board settings as Templates in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

Our team made several changes to the available settings on the Boards of Visual Studio Team Services. I would like to know if there's a way to save these settings as templates in order to apply it to new projects and teams.

Answer (score 1):

No this is currently not possible. [The ALM Rangers are working on a project which will allow you to copy/paste board configs from one team to another.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/12/14/early-overview-kanban-board-configuration-export-extension/) JSON import/export is planned for the future. For now we'd like to get simple apply from master working.

We may open up for beta tests soon.

Comment: I suppose this should be part of the Process Template. I hope this to come soon.

Comment: The base board is part of the process template. The rest is custom and I suppose it will stay so.