# Is it possible to export/import board configuration from TFS (or Azure DevOps)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I've to create several very similar projects in TFS.

It is possible to export and import several TFS configuration, for instance, work items and process definition.

Is it possible to do the same for board configuration? For instance, column, card and tag style rules?

Answer (score 1):

Try this tool [Azure Boards Kanban Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alm-devops-rangers.KanbanBoardTools). It copies configuration between boards.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is export and import Board settings as Templates.

Unfortunately, there is **no such build-in setting or configuration** in Azure DevOps Server(TFS)/Azure DevOps Service.

> You could submit a user voice. Our PM will kindly review any
>   suggestion.
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea

Besides, you could also try to use that extension Azure Boards Kanban Tools release by Azure DevOps Rangers. It seems come from here, take a look at this similar question: [Is it possible to save Board settings as Templates in VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494761/is-it-possible-to-save-board-settings-as-templates-in-vsts)